# Adding vbnewline into strings VBA

Tags: vba, officedev

Ok when i was finally able to solve (with StackOverflow assistance) my arranging entries by time function, I was presented with a new issue.

It no longer followed the rules of the template i have attached to it. Not a huge problem because i thought of a quick solution but its not working.

I have added a function below, purpose:

1. split the string passed to it -theSentence- into the array -theWords()-
2. find out if the string -final- (do while loop adds each word from array to string one at a time) if more than 56 length
3. if -final- is more than 56 length then add vbnewline to the string before adding next word
4. change original string -theSentnce- to equal the created string -final- which should have a vbnewline in it after approx 56 length

.... not working need a push in the right direction probably something stupid

```
  Function chckLen(ByVal theSentence As String)

  Dim theWords() As String
Dim final As String
Dim arrayCntr As Integer
Dim arrayAmount As Integer
Dim chcker As Integer


 arrayCntr = 0

   theWords = Split(theSentence)
  arrayAmount = UBound(theWords)
  chcker = 56

  Do While arrayCntr <= arrayAmount

   If Len(final + theWords(arrayCntr)) > chcker Then
     final = final + vbNewLine
      final = final + theWords(arrayCntr)
     chcker = chcker + 56
   Else
     final = final + " " + theWords(arrayCntr)
   End If
         arrayCntr = arrayCntr + 1
  Loop

  theSentence = final

End Function
```

Comment: `not working` is not descriptive at all!

Comment: Why are you giving `TheSentence` the `final` string? This should be given to `chcklen` if you use a Function. Otherwise it should just be a `Sub`

Comment: i figured it out thanks, i ended up just taking away the byval in order to effect -theSentence- but out of curiosity and since im teaching myself all of this if i have 

chkLen = final

will that work the same way ?

Comment: @aethanskot What was the issue?

Comment: @dragonsamu the issue was:

Function chckLen(ByVal theSentence As String)

vs

Function chckLen(theSentence As String)

Comment: What is your delimiter for the `Split` function?

Comment: @fred correct me if i am mistaken but by not designating a delimeter it uses " " as the default

Comment: no you are correct. Got to be honest, I didn't know that.  However I do think its easier to read if you specify the delimiter even if it is the default.

Comment: thank you, i may look into adding that, the program is very compartmentalized so this is the only instance where i use this type of function but if i run into problems in the future ill know why